# Ubuntu 20.04 - Difficult problem - Full disk encryption backup to new SSD

Tags: 20.04, ssd

I have a bit of a tricky issue

I installed Ubuntu 18 a year ago, setting up full disk encryption as I did so, with password on boot. I have since upgraded to 20.04.

Now I have discovered my SSD needs to be replaced.

I was wondering if any experts knew of a way in which I could copy my existing system to the new ssd, perhaps by backing up the drive to an external hd, and then copying to the new ssd. Or by some other means. I simply need to transfer my existing setup to the new ssd.

Another issue I face is that the new ssd also needs to have full disk encryption

Any help much appreciated, this is causing me a great deal of stress

Comment: Hi, I don't need to upgrade Ubuntu. I just want to copy 20.04 on one encrypted ssd, to another

Comment: ah ok I see, i don't think this matters in this instance as ubuntu itself is not encrypted? This is full disk encryption. I am using 20.04

Comment: If your new SSD is as big as your old SSD you should be able to exactly clone the system using dd. (dd does not allow any errors).  `sudo if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` has always worked for me, were sda is the old SSD and sdb is the new SSD, but I have not tried it with encrypted drives but I am sure it will work. Confirm this before proceeding.

Comment: hi, yes the new ssd is larger. i assume I connect the new SSD via USB, use DD to copy my system to it?, and then open the laptop and switch the SSD's?

Comment: Yes that is how to do it. Run the dd process from a Live or Persistent USB so neither SSD is active at the time.

Comment: given the new ssd is larger, would i need to expand the LUKS container?

Comment: I do not know, I think expand the LUKS container when required.